# angular and eval: i get an error with environment

Tags: angular, eval, environment

I do this:

```js
let var1="environment.test";
console.log(eval(var1));
```

I get the error:
ERROR ReferenceError: environment is not defined

If i do
console.log(environment.test);
it works

If i do

```js
let var1="var2";
let var2="myvalue";
console.log(var1);
console.log(eval(var1));
```

it works.
The problem is 'environment'.
How can I do?
Thx a lot

Comment: FYI using eval is not a good idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using eval. See this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!).

However to use it once you import environment like this:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

You can use it with eval like this:

```
export class AppComponent {

  environment = environment;

  constructor() {
    console.log('prefered way:', environment.test); // <-- use this instead
    let var1 = "this.environment.test";
    console.log(eval(var1));
  }
```

Comment: @fredericlanglois 
Wonderful! Please mark this as the answer if it solved your issue :) Thank you!